# Problems with using numbers and italic greek of Alegreya font in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

I started to set up a template document with `Alegreya` as font which is supposed to be compilable on all three engines, PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX. To also set `Alegreya` as the math font, I have chosen `mathastext` package because this works for all three engines. But I don't get numbers and greek symbols in math mode to be taken from the font. I tried several things, this is what I have at the moment:

*(Please note, that I want **all** greek letters in math to appear in italics. I just used `\mathit` for demonstration purposes.)*

**MWE 1:** Using `Alegreya` package

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage[
    LGRgreek,% use greek letters from main font
    italic,
    itgreek,
]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
abcdef + αβγδεζ + 12345\\
\textit{abcdef + αβγδεζ + 12345}\\ 
$abcdef + \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\zeta + 12345$\\
$\mathit{abcdef + \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\zeta} + 12345$
\end{document}
```

- PDFLaTeX:

  - text: greek: yes
  - math: numbers: yes, upright greek: yes*, italic greek: no*
- LuaLaTeX & XeLaTeX:

  - text: greek: yes
  - math: numbers: no, upright greek: yes*, italic greek: no*

*The 3rd line in the document gives upgright greek which does not look like the default font but differs from the upright text greek. The 4th line gives latin letters.

**MWE 2:** Using `fontspec` package to at least compile with Lua/XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    %Path={Fonts/Alegreya/},% required to get italic text greek in XeLaTeX
    %Extension = .otf,% .ttf,% no difference
    Ligatures=TeX,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]{Alegreya}

\usepackage[
    LGRgreek,% use greek letters from main font
    italic,
    itgreek,
]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
abcdef + αβγδεζ + 12345\\
\textit{abcdef + αβγδεζ + 12345}\\ 
$abcdef + \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\zeta + 12345$\\
$\mathit{abcdef + \alpha\beta\gamma\delta\zeta} + 12345$
\end{document}
```

- LuaLaTeX: same as in MWE 1 with correct numbers in math now.
- XeLaTeX: same as in MWE 1 with correct numbers but missing italic greek in text mode. Defining the path to the font files in my directory is required to get the italic greek characters in text althought font is installed on my system.

Before installing I checked that the font contains greek letters. I tried the true type and the open type font versions and I tried to specify the extension. But this makes no differences in the output.

**MWE 3:** Using `unicode-math` instead of `mathastext`

I changed `\usepackage[...]{mathastext}` in MWE 2 to:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Alegreya}
```

This is of course not working, the output is math in default font with missing signes for the greek letters inside `\mathit`. So, I changed the `unicode-math` part to this:

**MWE 4:** [Modified `unicode-math` solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259111/setting-math-fonts-with-mathspec-changes-monotype-fonts-of-urls-in-bibliography)

```
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,Digits},Numbers={Lining}]{Alegreya-Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,Digits},Numbers={Lining}]{Alegreya}
```

- LuaLaTeX:

  - textgreek and mathgreek: yes
  - numbers: no
- XeLaTeX: same as MWE 3.

I do know that it is possible [for XeLaTeX to get `Alegreya` in math with `mathspec`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292769/alegreyasans-with-mathspec-in-beamer/292784). But since my document is planned as a template for all three engines it would be nice to have a more general solution. If this is not possible, I'd like to, at least, get the numbers work for LuaLaTeX and MWE 4. Somehow it seems, I only get the correct greek OR correct numbers, but not both.

**Probably related:**

- [Italic greek letters become latin letters in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379890/italic-greek-letters-become-latin-letters-in-math-mode/379985#379985). I don't feel well with this solution. I don't want to 'fake' a slanted version when the font definitely contains italic greek. In addition this is only a local solution that requires placing the command everytime, whereas I am looking for a global option.
- [Get font Alegreya working with greek letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369194/get-font-alegreya-working-with-greek-letters). This is a combination of two different fonts to substitute the greek in `Alegreya`, but I don't want to combine two fonts.
- [How to use Alegreya Sans for math mode on pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333186/how-to-use-alegreya-sans-for-math-mode-on-pdflatex). In this example (like MWE 1), the greek looks wrong to me, too. (I am not sure about the numbers, because they are in exponents.)
- [Mimicking mathspec practices in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317862/mimicking-mathspec-practices-in-lualatex). In this solution (like MWE 2), greek letters are not discussed.

The font can be downloaded [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya). After selection it is possible to costumize the font shapes and greek letters.

Comment: when trying https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya the Firefox window remains despairingly  blank. Same for https://fonts.google.com/ ...

Comment: Both links work for me. The window is loaded after a few seconds.

Comment: waiting for 20 seconds now and page remains blank. Does one need some kind of google account? Or is private browsing mode the problem? or perhaps the sandboxing of recent firefox which already caused problems for rendering of some pages like wikipedia because I had configured Firefox to use DejaVu from TeXLive? back to https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya still waiting...

Comment: The problem appears to be that TeX Live ships with an old TTF version of Alegreya that doesn’t contain any Greek letters. I’m putting the finishing touches on a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem you were having was that TeX Live currently ships with an old version of Alegreya that doesn’t contain any Greek letters.  If you download and install [the newer version of the OTF files](https://github.com/huertatipografica/Alegreya/tree/master/fonts/otf), you will be able to load them in either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, by their filenames.  (This should still work if your TeX distribution ever updates its version of the font.)

Additionally, the commands you were using to load the partial math font in `unicode-math` do not appear to be correct as of version 0.8l.  You might want to make sure you have [up-to-date documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math).

Here is a solution for Greek and Latin letters in upright, italic, bold and bold italic alphabets, as well as numbers in upright and bold (italic digit symbols are not in Unicode 10.0).

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} % Workaround for standalone 1.2 and LuaTeX.
\documentclass[preview,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers=Lining}
\setmathfont{Alegreya-Italic.otf}[range=it/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]
\setmathfont{Alegreya-Regular.otf}[range=up/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num}]
\setmathfont{Alegreya-BoldItalic.otf}[range=bfit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]
\setmathfont{Alegreya-Bold.otf}[range=bfup/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek,num}]
\newfontfamily\Alegreya{Alegreya-Regular.otf}[
  BoldFont=Alegreya-Bold.otf,
  ItalicFont=Alegreya-Italic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=Alegreya-BoldItalic.otf]

\begin{document}
{\Alegreya Alegreya: abcxyzαβγδ123 \textit{abcxyzαβγδ} \textbf{abcxyzαβγδ123} \textbf{\textit{abcxyzαβγδ}}}

\[\symup{abcxyzαβγδ123}\,\symit{abcxyzαβγδ}\,\symbfup{abcxyzαβγδ123}\,\symbfit{abcxyzαβγδ}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Alegreya test]

That defines `\Alegreya` for compatibility with the package.  It does not completely set up the font family, such as the different weights, small caps, sans-serif, or the sans-serif math alphabets, but the `unicode-math` documentation will show how to do that if you need it.

If you have a mostly-working preamble for PDFLaTeX, the way to make a template that will work in PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is to use the package `iftex` to detect your TeX engine and wrap the fallback version in a conditional block.  So, `\ifPDFLaTeX` ... `\else` ... `\fi`.

#### Update

As of March 2019, `alegreya` has been updated and now makes everything easier.

It supports the LGR encoding, if you compile with PDFLaTeX or load the `[type1]` option.  This means that you can now load `\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}`, `\usepackage[type1]{alegreya}`, and use its LGR encoding for your Greek math letters with `mathastext` or `isomath`.

The package will set up `fontspec` if compiled with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  You can still use the technique above with `unicode-math` (which I recommend), or load `alegreya` and then `mathastext` in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, or use `mathspec` in XeLaTeX.

#### The Rest of the Original Answer

The `Alegreya` package cannot support Greek letters like you want, according to the documentation, because under NFSS, Greek text letters are in the LGR encoding, and you told `mathastext` to take its math symbols from that.  However, `Alegreya` only supports the OT1, T1, TS1 and LY1 encodings.

The following preamble *mostly* works for loading another font that does support Greek, GFS Bodoni: (It does not include an italic face, but another could be substituted.)

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} % Workaround for standalone 1.2 and LuaTeX.
\documentclass[preview,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english,greek]{babel} % Use this if you are writing in Greek.
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{gfsbodoni}
\usepackage[italic, LGRgreek, itgreek]{mathastext} % or upgreek, or upGreek.

\DeclareSymbolFont{bodoniup}{LGR}{bodoni}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\greekup}{bodoniup}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bodonibf}{LGR}{bodoni}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\greekbf}{bodonibf}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mathup[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}
{abcxyzαβγδ123 \textit{abcxyzαβγδ} \textbf{abcxyzαβγδ123} \textit{\textbf{abcxyzαβγδ}}}

\[ abcxyzαβγδ123 \quad
  \mathup{abcxyz}\greekup{αβγδ}\mathup{123} \quad
  \mathbf{abcxyz}\greekbf{αβγδ}\mathbf{123}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The one thing this breaks is Greek letters in `\mathit`, `\mathbf` and the other math alphabets.  With `mathastext` and the legacy T1 and LGR font encodings, these set the alphabet to the T1 encoding, not the LGR encoding.  So, `\mathit{α}` will become *a*, `\mathrm{γ}` will become g, and `\mathbf{δ}` will become **d**.  If you need multiple styles of Greek math symbols in the same document, or you want to use µ and π according to ISO style, you need to use the workaround.  [It’s inspired by jfbu’s answer here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401534/4686)

Also note that that is correct for ISO style, but to get the default behavior of TeX, which is slanted lowercase and upright uppercase Greek, use the `upGreek` option.

Comment: mentioning https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401534/4686 for Greek letters, mathastext, and math alphabets (which are misnomers because they are meant to use the text fonts in math mode)

Comment: @jfbu And also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398440/use-smart-greek-letters-recognizing-mathrm-with-mathastext-package

Comment: @jfbu Incorporated your approach into my second answer. Thanks!

Comment: more upvotes needed here `;-)`

Comment: Thank you! I now managed to implement Alegreya and AlegreyaSans completely for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Btw, it is a very good idea to define compatibility commands (`\Alegreya`, etc.). I had not thought about that. Did that for all package commands, now. I already use `ifxetex`, `ifluatex` and `iftex`. I'd just left them out to keep the MWEs minimal. (Is there some advantage of using `iftex` compared to the other packages?) For PDFLaTeX I am going to use your workaround. I don't find it really satisfying but I get the problem with the math fonts now, and for that seems the best solution.

Comment: @Lysanne You probably thought of this already, but if you want the same code to work in the modern solution and the workaround, you’d need to have the `unicode-math` version define `\greekup` as `\symup`, `\greekit` as `\symit` and so on, then use them in the document itself if you need a non-default glyph. You might try just skipping the workaround and loading `lmodern` before `Alegreya` so at least you’ll get consistent results. There are a few GFS packages, such as `Artemisia`, that set up the math alphabets too.

Comment: @Lysanne I don’t know of any advantage to `\usepackage{iftex}` other than being slightly shorter to write than `\usepackage{lfxetex, iflualatex, ...}`.